# Shutil.copyfileobj Load line after line using time.sleep()

Tags: python, file, printing, shutil

I already know how to print a file to stdout using **shutil.copyfileobj**, it's done like this:

```
with open('filename.extension', 'r') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)
```

Unfortunately for me, when it does this, it prints the whole file all at once. I don't want it to do this. I want it to gradually print line after line, with a pause in between printing each line using **time.sleep()**. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: To do that, you'll need to read and write the file line by line, rather than using a low-level copy operation.

Comment: @user3553031 And how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with open('filename.extension', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It works, but if there are more that 2 lines in the file, it will include a new line after every two lines. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Try searching how to print without newlines in Python.

Comment: Or could I just do __file.strip('\n')__?

Comment: Still can't find anything related to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Figured it out, I have to add a comma to the end like this: __print(line),__